# Add 5 second delay before video autoplays

Tags: video.js

I'm trying to add a 5 second delay to video.js before it starts auto-playing, but can't figure out how to with this implementation:

```
$('.video-js').each(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    var id = element.attr('id').replace('#', '');
    var heading_links = element.parents('.post-images-wrapper').find('.pcos-heading-links');

    _V_(id).ready(function() {
        var video_player = this, options = video_player.options();

        if (options.autoplay) { heading_links.hide(); }

        video_player.on('ended', function() {  
            video_player.posterImage.show();  
            video_player.currentTime(0);  
            video_player.controlBar.hide();  
            video_player.bigPlayButton.show();  
            video_player.cancelFullScreen();
            heading_links.show();  
        });  

        video_player.on('play', function() {
            video_player.posterImage.hide();  
            video_player.controlBar.show();  
            video_player.bigPlayButton.hide();
            heading_links.hide();
        });  

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `_V_` then you're probably on an old version of video.js. Later versions just use `videojs` This should still work, but you should also upgrade.

First make sure you no longer have the `autoplay` attribute on your video tag. Then:

```
_V_(id).ready(function(){
  var player = this;

  setTimeout(function(){
    player.play();
  }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: So I can edit what I have like this?

setTimeout(function(){    
   video_player.on('play', function() {
            video_player.posterImage.hide();  
            video_player.controlBar.show();  
            video_player.bigPlayButton.hide();
            heading_links.hide();
        });
 }, 5000);

Comment: I can't really follow everything you're trying to do, but why don't you try it out and see.

Comment: Thanks, it works but I used video_player.play() instead of player.play();